# Multithreaded network crawler threads limit

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have access to an application written in .NET C# which connects (using mainly "raw" http requests, partially web services and xml requests, still over http) to numerous external systems and updates some stuff in them.

There can be alot of work queued at a given time and the naive approach to increase the throughput was to increase the threads count. The logic behind it was: since most of the time we are waiting for network replies, we can simultaneously wait for more network replies. The cpu and ram does not seem to be raching their limits.

Still creating around 300 threads makes everything work slower than with lower thread counts.

I am wondering is it an operating system limit (windows server 2012 r2), the .NET (4.5) limit or something else? How can I diagnose where is the bottleneck? (as I said the cpu and ram does not seem to be the problem)

I know the external systems might get overloaded and decrease overall performance, but lets assume this is negligible.

Comment: `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` **might** be the issue.

Comment: Exact Windows version? Both their maximum number and their management is pretty different.

Comment: @AgentFire It seems like the direct cause of the problem I had was actualy this limit. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely problems are:

1. As AgentFire indicated in a comment, the [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) property will limit the number of concurrent connections you can have to a single domain. The default value is 2. If you're trying to get a lot of data from a single server in multiple requests, you're going to be limited. You can increase this value if you need to. Be aware, though, that the server might see your multiple connections as an attempted denial of service attack, and block or throttle you.
2. It appears that *something* in the .NET HTTP stack is single-threaded. I suspect that it's in DNS resolution. I've found that it's easy to maintain throughput of 15 to 20 requests per second using multiple threads. This of course depends on the size of the documents you're downloading and the responsiveness of the servers you're communicating with, but my experience running a crawler was that the naive method (one request per thread using `HttpWebRequest`), I ended up averaging 15 to 20 requests per second.

In the case of #2, I suspect DNS because I ran a separate test in which I did DNS resolution on the domains I was working with, and my average was 50 to 60 milliseconds per request. Most came back real quick, but some took several seconds. Also, my throughput increased significantly when I put a big DNS cache on the local network.

CPU and memory aren't going to be your limiting factors. In addition to DNS resolution, you have to take into account your connection speed. If you have 10 concurrent connections, each of which is downloading from a server at the rate of 1 Mb/sec, you're going to saturate a 10 Mb/s Internet connection. You should be looking at the network bandwidth you're using.

Those are the biggest bottlenecks, in my experience. You should investigate each of those to see if any one or more is the reason for your perceived poor performance.

Comment: Actually the default connection limit is 10 on servers (see Note in th elink you provided). Was still too low for our needs. Thank you for other remarks, they were helpful as well.

Comment: I chose this as the correct answer because the first point was the actual problem in my case.

Comment: @user1713059 why didn't you choose the original source's answer as accepted then?

Comment: I don't undesrand  what you mean, you are asking me why I didnt mark your comment below the question as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 5):

Creating a thread requires **some** CPU and RAM, 300 thread creations allocate at least 1 MB per thread plus stack allocations plus some other stuff.

You should use the thread pool for that. The threads in the pool are already created and are waiting to serve you.

In case of a long waiting for the network response you could use the [asynchronous IO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) algorythm which wont require many threads.

Comment: What you wrote is true and I agree, but it seems like the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` would still limit the number of used tcp ports and slow our network operation.

Comment: @user1713059 then take the advise in my comment at your question and increase the limit.

Answer (score 2):

When you have plenty of RAM available 300 threads are not a problem at all. Most people instinctively deride such an architecture. The same people have never tested it themselves. It works just fine. OS-caused performance problems start to matter in the 10000+ range on my Win7 system. The OS becomes jerky to use.

I'd still prefer async IO in your case because your thread count is quite high. **Still, sync IO is likely not your problem.**

> How can I diagnose where is the bottleneck?

Check all possible bottlenecks. Neither CPU nor RAM are one. Check network utilization. Are you using the disk? Are you sure your external services are not maxed out? They might have a concurrency limit.

I assume you have raised the .NET connection limits?! Find out, how many requests are actually being made concurrently. I'd do that by:

1. Pausing the debugger and making sure that many threads are currently in the .NET web stack.
2. Looking at the number of open TCP connections (Process Explorer or TcpView.exe)
3. Using Fiddler and seeing how many requests seem to be active at the same time.

Comment: I agree, the cause of my problem was not the sync IO, but the default connection limit in `ServicePointManager`. Thank you for your input.